# How to use method getInitialProps from next.js to get cookies?

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js

I'm facing an issue with next.js

I cannot get my cookies when i make a request from `async static getInitialProps`. i get `undefined`

However when i am making it in `componentWillMount` there is no problem. Unfortunately, it's too late because i need to get the cookie info before the component be called. So i need to get it in `getInitialProps`

Here what i've already tried without success :

```js
static async getInitialProps () {
      const res = await axios.get('http://mybackend/getCookie');
      return {data : res.data}
    }
    
    //res.data = undefined
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may be a client vs server thing - `componentWillMount()` only runs on the client, so requests there would always include the client's cookies. However, `getInitialProps` may run on the server, and in that case you'll have to manually set the cookies.

You can tell if it's running on the client vs server by testing for the presence of options.req:

```
static getInitialProps({ req }) {
  if (req) {
    console.log('on server, need to copy cookies from req')
  } else {
    console.log('on client, cookies are automatic')
  }
  return {};
}
```

And, when running on the server, you can read the client's cookies by checking `req.headers.cookie`. So, with axios, it might look something like this:

```
static async getInitialProps({req}) {
  const res = await axios({
    url: 'http://mybackend/getCookie',
    // manually copy cookie on server,
    // let browser handle it automatically on client
    headers: req ? {cookie: req.headers.cookie} : undefined,
  });
  return {data : res.data}
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. You finally help me to fix an issue that i am struggling with since almost 48h. I was focus on making a `req.cookies` i never tried to do the magic `req.headers.cookie` that made the whole deal. Now everything works just as expected. Many thanks !!

Comment: Yea, a lot of cookie parsing libraries store the result at req.cookies, but the original/raw value is just in the headers.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm using this method to be able to grab some initial data in getInitialProps while rendering server-side, but are there any security implications of doing so?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I think it may send this code to the client even though it only executes server-side, so be careful about including credentials or anything else you want to keep secret in there, but that's basically true of everything with next.js.

Comment: @earliee just include the classics security diligences for XRF, XSS, and MITM

Answer (score 2):

If using isomorphic-fetch api, and the route needs authentication, this will send client cookies if server side rendering, i.e. first page load.

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

  let clients = await fetch(
  `
  ${API_SERVER}/client/clients`,
    ctx.req ? {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie
      }
    } : {}
  );
}
```